# jquery menu slide and change button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate

ok so im using the slide menu from here [slide menu](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/#) and i want to change the button text when its clicked to say show or hide for example,this is the code i have for only top menu so far on my offline install

```html
<button id="showTop" class="menubtn" data-text-swap="Show">Show</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
  <script>
   var menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
    showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
    body = document.body;

  
   showTop.onclick = function() {
    
    classie.toggle( this, 'active1' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
   };
   

   function disableOther( button ) {

    if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
     classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
    }

   }
   
  </script>
```

I tried something mentioned in another post

```html
$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
    if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
        $this.text('See More');         
    } else {
        $this.text('See Less');
    }
});
```

but that didnt help so is there something i can do to the first script under the showTop.onclick function to also change button text and not just class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing this from within your click function:

```
showTop.onclick = function() {

    if (showTop.innerHTML == 'Show') {

        showTop.innerHTML = 'Hide';

    } else { 

        showTop.innerHTML = 'Show';

    };
```

Comment: omg ty that worked so good i spend a good 3 hours tryin to make the button work XD button took more time than menu :P